# React upload file to mongodb node Js multer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

I am trying to upload an image to a mongodb database from a react component. I have tried all the possible ways but the backend is returning an  undefined in the console. Here is the code I am struggling with
First the react form

```
<div className="md:w-1/2 h-7 m-auto mt-8 border-gray-900 rounded shadow-md">
    <form encType='multipart/form-data' className="m-auto text-center rounded h-auto px-8 border-gray-900">
      <div className="inline-block container m-auto pb-6 flex items-center py-2">
        <input className='hidden' name='StudentImage' type="file" onChange={this.fileSelectedHandler}
      </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
```

then the selection handler

```
fileSelectedHandler = e => {
    console.log(e.target.files[0]);
    this.setState({
      StudentImage: e.target.files[0]
    });
    const data = new FormData() 
    data.append('StudentImage', this.state.StudentImage);
    axios.post('http://localhost:4000/students/image',data)
    console.log(this.state.StudentImage.lastModified)
  };
```

and the node js backend code

```
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, 'assets/images')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
  })

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/png' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg') {
        cb(null, true);
    } else {
        cb(null, false);
    }
};
const upload = multer({storage: storage, limits: { fileSize: '4MB' }, fileFilter: fileFilter}).single("StudentImage")

const router = express.Router();
router.post('/image', upload, async (req, res)=>{    
    console.log(req.file);

})
```

and the `console.log(req.file);` line is printing out undefined

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is asynchronous, so you're not guaranteed to have access to the new state value when you try to append `this.state.StudentImage` to `data`:

```
    this.setState({
      StudentImage: e.target.files[0]
    });
    const data = new FormData() 
    data.append('StudentImage', this.state.StudentImage);
```

`this.setState` takes a second argument, a callback that gives you access to the new state, so this might work better:

```
    this.setState({
      StudentImage: e.target.files[0]
    }, () => {
      const data = new FormData() 
      data.append('StudentImage', this.state.StudentImage);
      axios.post('http://localhost:4000/students/image',data)
      console.log(this.state.StudentImage.lastModified)
    });
```

Or just use `StudentImage` instead of `this.state.StudentImage`, which would be a little simpler:

```
    const StudentImage = e.target.files[0];
    this.setState({ StudentImage });
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('StudentImage', StudentImage);
    axios.post('http://localhost:4000/students/image',data)
    console.log(StudentImage.lastModified)
```

The other thing: In node, I think you want `req.body` instead of `req.file`.